# Excel index/match and index/aggregate text search not working

Tags: excel

I'm trying to search for a partial text match with wildcards and I'm not having any success.  I have two criteria i'm searching for and the second one, which is the partial text match, never works.  Any reason why the text search isn't working?

I'm working in Office 365

```
=IF(D18=TRUE,IF(ISTEXT(INDEX('Sheet1'!F:F,MATCH(1,(A18='Sheet1'!B9510:B9512)*("*Confirmed Fraud*"='Sheet1'!E9510:E9512),0))),"Good","Bad"))

=IF(D18=TRUE,IF(ISTEXT(INDEX('Sheet1'!E9510:E9512,AGGREGATE(15,4,ROW('Sheet1'!E9510:E9512)/(('Sheet1'!E9510:E9512="*Confirmed Fraud*")),1))),"Good","Bad"))
```

Comment: Use of wild cards in an equality is not valid.

Comment: use: `ISNUMBER(SEARCH())`

Comment: @ScottCraner I tried using your suggestion and the issue I came up with is multiple matches with the criteria I'm searching for, but they're not in the same row.  If row 9510 matches criteria1 and row 9512 matches criteria2 then it will come back as a positive match.  It should only come back as a positive match when both criteria match on the same row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an easier way to solve this.  I created a flag for the text that I was trying to search for.  I search for the flag instead of the text which makes it much easier.